# Java: Mocked object not being injected in method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

The lines of code that I want to test is:

```
private static final EntityType WORK_FLOW_ENTITY_TYPE = //Assigned
public WorkflowRequest getWFRequestFromHerdInput(HerdInput herdInput) throws
        NonRetriableException {
    ActionRequest request = CoralHerdUtils.getRequestData(herdInput);
    Document document = request.getHerdDocument();
    List<Entity> entityList = document.getEntitiesByType(WORK_FLOW_ENTITY_TYPE);
    Entity entity = entityList.get(0);
    WorkflowRequest workflowRequest = null;
    try {
        workflowRequest = (WorkflowRequest) entity.asCommonsObject();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        throw new NonRetriableException("Object cannot be converted to WorkflowRequest");
    }
    return workflowRequest;
}
```

I want to test the catch part of the try-catch. I am using PowerMockito and Mockito both. For testing, I have written the following:

```
@Test(expected = NonRetriableException.class)
public void test_GetWFRequestFromHerdInput_fail() throws NonRetriableException, DocumentException {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(CoralHerdUtils.class);
    PowerMockito.when(CoralHerdUtils.getRequestData(herdInput)).thenReturn(actionRequest);
    EntityType WORKFLOW_ENTITYTYPE = new EntityType(new Aspect("DigitalInfluence"),
            "Application", "1.0");
    DocumentFactory docFactory = new DocumentFactory();
    docFactory.registerCommonsClass(WorkflowRequest.class, WORKFLOW_ENTITYTYPE);
    document = docFactory.createDocument();
    document.addEntity(workflowRequest);
    Mockito.when(actionRequest.getHerdDocument()).thenReturn(document);
    List<Entity> entities = Mockito.mock(List.class);
    Entity entity = Mockito.mock(Entity.class);
    entities.add(entity);
    Document documentMock = Mockito.mock(Document.class);
    Mockito.when(documentMock.getEntitiesByType(WORKFLOW_ENTITYTYPE)).thenReturn(entities);
    Mockito.when(entities.get(0)).thenReturn(entity);
    Mockito.when(entity.asCommonsObject()).thenThrow(DocumentException.class);

    WorkflowRequest workflowRequestReturned = herdDocumentHelper.getWFRequestFromHerdInput(herdInput);
    Assert.assertEquals(EXPECTED_DAG_ID, workflowRequestReturned.getDagId());
}
```

The problem is the test case is not picking the mocked Entity object but `entityList.get(0)` which is created inside the method.

How can I forcefully inject the mocked object in the method so that I can test the catch branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer is: you have to understand what mocking is and how it works.

Just creating a mock object somewhere doesn't magically "get" that object into your code under test.

Thus a distinct non-answer: **learn** how mocking frameworks work, and then apply that to your current code base (as outlined in the answer by user talex). Start reading [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html) for example.

Btw: so far, nothing in your production code justifies to use PowerMock(ito). So, if possible, stay with plain Mockito.

Comment: Updated the test case.

Comment: Because I was mocking without understanding (1.5 yrs back). Now I understand UTs in Java. Upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock:

- `CoralHerdUtils.getRequestData` to return mocked `ActionRequest`
- `request.getHerdDocument` to return mocked `Document`
- `document.getEntitiesByType` to return list containing your mocked `entity`

Comment: Updated the test case. Still it is not injecting the mock in the test case.